# Backspace trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, console-application

Why this my Python clock runs only from Python2, Python3 does nothing.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
wipe = '\b'*len(time.asctime())
print("The current date and time are: "+' '*len(wipe), end='')
while True:
    print(wipe+time.asctime(), end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, you need to flush the print buffer to force the characters to be written to the screen.

Add

```
import sys
```

to the start of your script and change the loop to

```
while True:
    print(wipe+time.asctime(), end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Actually, this should also be necessary for Python 2.x (at least when using the print function).

Comment: On my system, it doesn't work without this in Python 2, either.

Comment: On my system (Windows 7 x64), it does work without this in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the python version, but rather that you forgot to flush the standard output. Try changing your code to:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sys
wipe = '\b'*len(time.asctime())
print("The current date and time are: "+' '*len(wipe), end='')
while True:
    print(wipe+time.asctime(), end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

sys.stdout only flushes when a newline is printed too.